# Datatable hit case sensitive unique constraint when add new row

Tags: vb.net, datatable, case-sensitive

I hit unique constraint when add new row in datatable.

my unique field is ID.

ID

==

abc

ABC

How to disable the sensitive case checking in datatable.

I use datatable.casesensitive = false before not work for me.

Comment: This is most likely a constraint in your database - what database engine are you using?

Comment: oracle 10 and xml i use

Answer (score 2):

Use CaseSensitive = true before setting the PrimaryKey property on the datatable and it will be case-sensitive.  I had the same problem and this is how I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebuild your unique constraint like this:

```
create unique index uk_MyTable_ID on MyTable(upper(ID));
```